# Joomla is not showing language filter

Tags: joomla

I'm working in a Joomla project, and I'm configuring the language manager extension. All work perfectly, if I select, "Use dropdown" I can see the dropdown with my language options and I can switch between them. But if I select don't show dropdown and select show flags, I can't see the languages flags on my site. If I inspect using firebug, I can see that the html module has been created, but the `<span>` that contains the flag image is hidden.

[image: Firebug html].

how can I fix it from my joomla admin? Thanks for your help :).

Comment: http://joomla.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Joomla version? It seems that there is any JavaScript running? - Try to put something into the CSS like .lazy_container{width: auto!important;} for testing...

Comment: Thank you... joomla 3.5. I Tried to modify the css with .lazy_container{width: auto!important;} but nothing happens.

Comment: Do you use a special template which generates that "lazy_container"? - Using the standard template protostar I don't have this <span> which disappears your flag item. Try to use another template.

Answer (score 0):

Please check it on your browser plugin "Ad Blocker"